# Getting Error when tried to read JSON structure in BigQuery table

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Below is the JSON that I am trying to read and the CODE for your perusal:

I am just having Issue in reading "fieldorders" section, when it doesnt have any values. I still need to show them blank values if it doesnt have any structure. I am able to read couple of other objects which have multiple sections without any Issue. when we have an object with out any values, I have issue and I need to just place null values incase if i dont find any values in that object.

```
Getting the below Error:

**Failed to coerce output value false to type ARRAY**
```

Sample  JSON file I am using to read the data:

```
{
  "projectnumber": "X.6001877",
  "operationnumber": "O.6001877.01",
  "opactivitynumber": "B.6001877.01.01",
  "jobtypes": null,
  "jobtypesinfo": [
    {
      "jobtype": "CC-SERV",
      "jobgroup": "CPS-CC",
      "staticattributes": [
        {
          "name": "OAJTOPT",
          "description": "OA Job Type OPT",
          "type": "Double",
          "value": 0.0,
          "uom": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actualactivitystartdate": "2018-01-17T05:00:00",
  "actualactivityenddate": "2018-01-29T05:00:00",
  "serverdatetime": null,
  "ServerDateTime": "2019-01-20T16:36:48.106",
  "projectSettings": null,
  "customerContacts": null,
  "actualequipments": null,
  "welldetails": [
    {
      "Number": "1-1IH",
      "Name": "XXXX 58-4X",
      "State": "PL",
      "Country": "Col",
      "Field": "LABCD",
      "Uwi": null,
      "Environment": "Land",
      "WellId": "0065",
      "Latitude": 3.8,
      "Longitude": -72.2,
      "Type": null,
      "WaterDepth": null,
      "WellPlaceholderId": null,
      "IsNonMasteredWell": false
    }
  ],
  "lastopeventid": null,
  "personnelassignmentinfo": null,
  "status": null,
  "accountingunit": null,
  "erpsystem": "ITT",
  "CreatedDate": "2020-01-20T16:36:48.106",
  "CreatedBy": "ABCD11",
  "LastModifiedDate": "2020-01-20T16:36:48.106",
  "LastModifiedBy": "ABCD11",
  "Id": "A.6001877.01.01",
  "country": {
    "Code": "CO",
    "Name": "CoOOOOOO"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "Attributes": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "OAOPDXAS",
        "AttributeDescription": "Activity OPD",
        "DataType": "Integer",
        "UOMType": "Dimensionless",
        "BaseUnit": "",
        "IsCalculated": true,
        "Values": null
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "OpActOPTime",
        "AttributeDescription": "OA Operating Time - OPT (HRS)",
        "DataType": "Float",
        "UOMType": "Dimensionless",
        "BaseUnit": "",
        "IsCalculated": true,
        "Values": null
      }
    ],
    "DailyAttributes": null,
    "MultiAttributes": null,
    "Id": "A.6001877.01.01"
  },
  "operationalevent": [
    {
      "operatingevent": {
        "projectnumber": "C.6001877",
        "operationnumber": "O.6001877.01",
        "operationactivitynumber": "X.6001877.01.01",
        "operationaleventdetails": {
          "status": null,
          "description": "Non-Operational Event",
          "plannedeventid": null,
          "jobgroup": null,
          "jobtype": null,
          "startdatetime": "2020-01-18T05:00:00",
          "enddatetime": "2020-01-15T05:00:00",
          "comments": "Non-Operational Event",
          "eventtype": "Project",
          "isdeleted": false,
          "category": "NonOperational",
          "islocked": false,
          "lockedon": "0001-01-01T05:00:00",
          "lockedby": null,
          "audittrailinfo": {
            "CreatedDate": "2020-01-20T15:36:17.816",
            "CreatedBy": "ABCD11",
            "LastModifiedDate": "2020-01-20T15:36:17.816",
            "LastModifiedBy": "ABCD1111",
            "Id": null
          },
          "personnel": {
            "assignment": [

            ]
          },
          "serverdatetime": "2018-01-20T16:36:56.185",
          "equipmentdata": {
            "equipmentassignments": [

            ]
          },
          "eventtypeattributes": null,
          "id": "E97A5DBC",
          "oesummary": null,
          "journal": null,
          "well": null,
          "isactive": true,
          "externaltransactionhistoryinfo": [
            {
              "status": "Pending",
              "message": null,
              "type": "MPT",
              "riteservicereporturl": null,
              "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "CreatedBy": null,
              "LastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "LastModifiedBy": null,
              "Id": null
            }
          ],
          "pnmconsumptiondata": {
            "pnmconsumptions": [

            ]
          }
        },
        "CreatedDate": "2018-01-20T16:36:56.185",
        "CreatedBy": "ABCD11",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2020-01-20T16:36:56.185",
        "LastModifiedBy": "ABCD11",
        "Id": "A.6001877.01.01_OperationalEvent_E97A5DBC"
      },
      "attributes": null
    }
  ],
  "attendance": [

  ],
  **"fieldorders": [

  ]**
}
```

**BigQuery SQL Code:**

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
    RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
            return jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
    """
    OPTIONS (
        library="gs://json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
    );

    SELECT job_id,oe_descr,
    attr_name,
    well_name,
    job_type,
    --field_id

    from lz.json_actuals,
    UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.operationalevent[*].operatingevent.operationaleventdetails.description')) oe_descr  with offset oedescr,
    UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.attributes.Attributes[*].AttributeName')) attr_name with offset attrb,
    UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.welldetails[*].Name')) Well_name with offset wll,
    UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.jobtypesinfo[*].jobtype')) job_type with offset jt,
    --UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.fieldorders[*].id')) field_id WITH OFFSET fld

  ;
```

Comment: just saying that you were not able to adopt other solution to your specific case does not help - you should provide all relevant details!

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Mikhail. I will give examples where it works and where it doesnt.

Comment: you should update your question with all details of The Question you want to ask. And instead of posting images you should post texts so we can play with your data and reproduce your use-case and most importantly will be able to help you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I tried to post my question in the form of text and provided the sample json and code iam executing in BigQuery. looks like the moderator is deleting them and  iam not sure if iam in violation of any policies here. Please request your help to guide me

Comment: Instead of posting answers to your question - you should just update your question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - thanks so much , as advised I have edited my Question with relevenat information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL and should resolve your issue with empty object

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<string>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
  if(result){return result;} 
  else {return [];}
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT --job_id,
  oe_descr,
  attr_name,
  well_name,
  job_type,
  field_id
from `lz.json_actuals`,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.operationalevent[*].operatingevent.operationaleventdetails.description')) oe_descr  with offset oedescr,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.attributes.Attributes[*].AttributeName')) attr_name with offset attrb,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.welldetails[*].Name')) Well_name with offset wll,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.jobtypesinfo[*].jobtype')) job_type with offset jt
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.fieldorders[*].id')) field_id WITH OFFSET fld
```

if to apply to sample data in  your question - result is

```
Row oe_descr                    attr_name   well_name   job_type    field_id     
1   Non-Operational Event       OAOPDXAS    XXXX 58-4X  CC-SERV     null     
2   Non-Operational Event       OpActOPTime XXXX 58-4X  CC-SERV     null
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this. This solves my Problem. I have used LEFT JOIN for all the fields, as we might encounter the blank array for any column and tested it and it works fine